# Create an excel table with linear values

Tags: microsoft-excel

Looking for a way to create an excel table, that will consist of a linear set of points.
This table will be built by entering `Xstart`, `Xend`, `Ystatrt`, `Yend` and the Number of Points. All should be linear. thanks.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Do you mean a chart of some sort?

Comment: Please share sample data & method you have tried so far,, will help us to fix the issue in better way!!

Comment: y = mx + c , what's your preferred m & c ?

Comment: c = 0, m is according to the Number of Points entered.

Answer (score 0):

The following works. It expects the five stated inputs in cells E1:E5. Those are in the first row of the `LET()` in the formula editor. Putting all input references in the first row makes them easy to find when changes are needed.

The inputs give the outer two points. The ones in between are found by calculating the `Rise over Run` for each coordinate in the inner points of the range.

What fills in the inner points is built using `SEQUENCE()`. The total rows it produces is found with Points-1, a single column used, and a starting value of 0 so the first use of it, on the starting point, has no effect, but the formula is still valid for all "Points" number of rows rather than needing the first point to use a unique formula, then another for the rest. And incremented by 1 each pair.

One could `ROUND()` to any decimal, or none at all. If the point pairs themselves are your goal, pick a rounding that suits the amount of "accuracy" you desire. If this formula is to be an input to another formula, or to something like a chart, and choppiness from the rounding is an issue, just increase the decimals at which the rounding occurs to suit, or remove the rounding altogether. After all, if having 15  digit long coordinates is not a problem, why bother rounding at all?

If you change the rounding often, add it to the first row. Add a term that looks like this:  `Decimals,2,` at the end of the row... I'll just edit that into the formula:

```
=LET(Xstart, E1,  Xend, E2,  Ystart, E3,  Yend, E4,  Points, E5-1,  Decimals, 2,
     Rise,  Yend-Ystart,  Run,  Xend-Xstart,
     Xdelta,  Run/Points,  Ydelta,  Rise/Points,
     XYpairs,
     "("& TEXT(ROUND(Xstart+Xdelta*SEQUENCE(Points+1,1,0,1),Decimals),"0.00")  &","&  TEXT(ROUND(Ystart+Ydelta*SEQUENCE(Points+1,1,0,1),Decimals),"0.00")  &")",
 
  XYpairs)
```

(The editor required some extra spaces here and there to lay it out nicely on the screen, but you can remove them. Lining things up in formulas makes them easier to follow, I believe.)

By rounding to at least two decimal places, one probably makes very sure the ending points match Xend and Xstart.

Excel has other functions for extending point sets. This stays within your stated available parameters so it looks nothing like those. If your stated available parameters are not truly what you'd like to do, rather being either due to the way your office worked this before thinking to use Excel, or you are not versed in what Excel can do so built what seemed a reasonable set of parameters to accomplish this, but might definitely prefer a different solution and be perfectly able to utilize the parameters it might need, posing the question but saying you are open to other methods would be a good way to see some of them.

(I do understand this is a couple years old, so OP will surely never see this answer, but someone searching the subject might like to know there are more ways to skin this cat.)